# how to capture the "new" client (data) by comparing yearly-firm client portfolio in R?

Tags: r

I have one database that contains the firms' names and ids and their clients' names and ids, which are structured yearly. So this means each firm has its unique client portfolio. I would like to find the "new" client per firm each year from this database, but I have no idea how to make it in R.

I appreciate any suggestions!

The current data looks like this:

```
client.id    client.name     year      firm.id     firm.name
   1            A             2013       1            AA
   1            A             2014       1            AA
   1            A             2015       1            AA    
   2            B             2015       1            AA
   1            A             2016       1            AA    
   2            B             2016       1            AA
   3            C             2016       1            AA
   4            D             2013       2            BB
   5            E             2013       2            BB
   5            E             2014       2            BB    
   6            F             2014       2            BB
   5            E             2015       2            BB    
   6            F             2015       2            BB
   7            G             2015       2            BB
```

What i would like to do is finding the new client for each firm per year:

```
client.id    client.name     year      firm.id     firm.name
   2            B            2015        1             AA
   3            C            2016        1             AA
   6            F            2014        2             BB
   7            G            2015        2             BB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to ask which clients are new for each firm per year is: what is the first year that each client appears for each firm?

We should also exclude the first year if that's when the data starts rather than truly indicating new clients:

```r
library(dplyr)

clients |> 
    group_by(firm.id, client.name) |>
    filter(
        year == min(year),
        year != min(clients$year)
    )

# # A tibble: 4 x 5
# # Groups:   firm.id, client.name [4]
#   client.id client.name  year firm.id firm.name
#       <int> <chr>       <int>   <int> <chr>
# 1         2 B            2015       1 AA
# 2         3 C            2016       1 AA
# 3         6 F            2014       2 BB
# 4         7 G            2015       2 BB
```